# What is the purpose of "/" character at the end of URL?

Tags: web

Some URLs end with `/`, for example https://www.gog.com/.

Comment: IIRc removing the char does have an effect and it should break the link. However many webservers are configured 'clippy' style. E.g. hey, this is wrong, lets see if it works if I change it a bit. Similar things can be seen on the other side of the web (in the browser), where `gog.com/` should be a file on your local computer and `http://gog.com/` should be a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trailing slash denotes a directory, while non-/ denotes a file.

When a directory is specified on an HTML URL, the web-server will return the
default file from the directory. This is usually `index.html` for the Linux Apache
server, or `default.htm` for Microsoft's Internet Information Services
(actually IIS tries in order default.htm, default.asp, index.htm, iisstart.htm).
For all web-servers it is possible to specify alternatives for these defaults.

If a directory name is specified without a slash, the result is the same,
but the browser will then need two requests, the first one returning only
the fact that the specified item is a directory (actually the answer is
a redirection to the URL with the slash appended).
Therefore, specifying the trailing slash for a directory is an optimization.

This is also true for the FTP protocol, except that the FTP server will return
as answer the contents of the directory.